# RequireJS: execute jQuery code domReady

Tags: requirejs

My **main.js** file looks like this:

```js
require.config({    
    paths: {
        "jquery": "3rd_party/jquery-2.0.3.min",
        "bootstrap": "3rd_party/bootstrap.min",
        "handlebars":"3rd_party/handlebars",
        "html5shiv":"3rd_party/html5shiv",
        "modernizr":"3rd_party/modernizr",
        "respond":"3rd_party/respond.min",
        "jquery-ui":"3rd_party/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min",
        'fancybox':'3rd_party/jquery.fancybox.pack'
    },

    shim: {
        "bootstrap": {
            deps: ["jquery"]
        },
        "jquery-ui": {
            deps: ["jquery"]
        },
        "fancybox": {
            deps: ["jquery"]
        }
    }
})

requirejs(["jquery", "fancybox","controllers/" + controller,'modules/login','bootstrap','handlebars','html5shiv','modernizr','respond', 'jquery-ui'],function($,fancybox,controller,handleLogin) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

        if ($(window).width()>991) {
            $(".sidebar").height($(".maincontent").height());   
        }

        $(".searchresults .greencol").height($(".searchresults .article").first().height()-100);
        $('.login').click(function() {
            handleLogin();
            return false;
        })
        $('.fancybox-inline').fancybox({
            maxWidth    : 800,
            maxHeight   : 600
        });
        $('.fancybox-document').fancybox({
            width: 660,
            height: 440
        });


        $('.fancybox-close-button').click(function() {
            $.fancybox.close();    
            return false;
        })



    });
    controller.init();
})
```

Now with everything happening, it actually takes some time to execute this bit:

```js
if ($(window).width()>991) {
    $(".sidebar").height($(".maincontent").height());   
}
```

And the page results in a little flicker. 
My only idea is to include jQuery separately in **index.html** and put this bit in `<script>`tags. But then my RequireJS setup broke.

Do you have any suggestions how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want the resizing to happen as early as possible. It's not completely clear to me how you tried to do it earlier but doing this is the way to make it happen as early as possible, and not break or bypass RequireJS:

1. Take the following out of your current `requirejs` callback:

   ```
   if ($(window).width()>991) {
       $(".sidebar").height($(".maincontent").height());   
   }
   ```
2. Add the following call to `requirejs` in front of your current call:

   ```
   requirejs(["jquery"], function($) {
       $(document).ready(function() {
          if ($(window).width()>991) {
               $(".sidebar").height($(".maincontent").height());   
           }
       });
   });
   ```

By the way, this does not need to be in a different `<script>` element. You can just put the new call to `requirejs` right in front of the one you already have. Done this way, the resizing will happen as soon as jQuery is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion that works perfectly. I always stuck with the "1 require per file" rule and didn't realize I could have more :)

Comment: Marked as accepted, but I don't have enough reputation to upvote, sorry